# how to return a value from a user defined function in matlab whose callback is specified in uicontrol

Tags: matlab, image-processing, uicontrol

I have the following code to run for resizing an image on a figure window. for this I wrote this code on a script file:

```
%%%f=figure('name','resize','color','w','windowstyle','modal','numbertitle','off','position',[820 110 500 612],'resize','on')
% Removed "'windowstyle','modal'" to allow debug
f=figure('name','resize','color','w','numbertitle','off', ...
         'position',[820 110 500 612],'resize','on')

hx=axes('Units','inches');

hax = imread('c.jpg');
imshow('c.jpg')
sli=uicontrol('Style','slider',...
    'Min',1,'Max',4,'Value',2,...
    'Position',[50 525 400 20],...
    'Callback', {@resiz,hax})

y=getappdata(0,'x');

uicontrol('Style','text',...
    'Position',[50 555 400 20],...
    'String','Resize');

uicontrol('Style','pushbutton',...
    'Position',[30 565 100 40],...
    'String','Save','Callback',{@save,y});
uicontrol('Style','pushbutton',...
    'Position',[200 565 100 40],...
    'String','Cancel','Callback',@cancel);
```

along with the above code I have a function definition code for resiz() which has save() and cancel() nested in it as follows:

```
function x=resiz(hObj,event,ax) %#ok<INUSL>

val =get(hObj,'Value');
if val==1
    v=256;
else
    v=(val-1)*2*256;
end
 s=[v v];
ax=imresize(ax,s);
  imshow(ax)
  setappdata(0,'x',ax);
function save(hObj,event,im)

  imwrite(im,'gt.jpg','jpg');
return

function cancel(hObj,event)
    close(hObj);
return
%%%return;
```

I have already gone through setappdata and getappdata but couldn't find any solution. Can anyone please help me get through this.

Answer (score 0):

I thinke wht you are looking for is **guidata**. Look at the segment with the example for 'Using guidata in a Programmatic UI'

Source: http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html?searchHighlight=guidata#zmw57dd0e268555